# Ubuntu 20.04 unable to detect any device that can be color managed

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, night-light

In the Colors section of the Settings, I am seeing this message: Unable to detect any device that can be color managed. Also, I think because of this my night light doesn't work. How can I fix the problem? The output for nvidia-smi command in the terminal is as following:

```
Mon Aug  7 20:50:36 2023       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 390.157                Driver Version: 390.157                   |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GT 525M     Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 N/A |                  N/A |
| N/A   87C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    222MiB /   964MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0                    Not Supported                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Also, the output of systemctl status colord is:

```
● colord.service - Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/colord.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2023-08-07 22:19:06 +0330; 12min ago
Process: 13368 ExecStart=/usr/libexec/colord (code=exited, status=127)
Main PID: 13368 (code=exited, status=127)

Aug 07 22:19:06 username systemd[1]: Starting Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles...
Aug 07 22:19:06 username systemd[1]: colord.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Aug 07 22:19:06 username systemd[1]: colord.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 07 22:19:06 username colord[13368]: /usr/libexec/colord: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgusb.so.2: undefined symbol: libusb_get_parent
Aug 07 22:19:06 username systemd[1]: Failed to start Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles.
```

Also:

```
libusb-1.0-0-dev is already the newest version (2:1.0.23-2build1).
```

Comment: This happened to me today on 22.04.3 (nVidia GPU). It seems to share some dependencies with night light as well. Same happened to me on 21.10 (AMD GPU). To be fair this it's quite rare, I encountered this behavior a couple of times throughout the year. As workaround, just re-login.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. Many people have solved this issue by restarting or logging out and logging in again. But my problem continued over 3-4 months. Finally, manually installing libusb has solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting help from [Intel Community](https://community.intel.com/t5/Items-with-no-label/zr300-ubuntu-16-04-server-edition-undefined-symbol-libusb-get/td-p/457606), I solved my problem. If you have the same problem, first you must download the latest version of `libusb` manually from [libsub website](https://libusb.info/). Then you must install it by:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

Finally, you should copy the .so files and links related to libusb from the `/usr/local/lib/` folder to `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` folder. Then restart Ubuntu.